# Add new text in combo box

Tags: combobox

In asp.net(c#) dev express combo box control.

I have one combo box named country. It is bind from database country table. But i need to add a new country name to the database through the combo box. I mean I have to enter the new country Name in combo box and that should add in Database, then bind on the same combo box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asp update panel to achieve this. Have the combo box and a button to add an extra item to the box all in the update panel. When you click the button, add the data to the database and then rebind the combo box.

Personally id rather using jquery, jquery ajax and asp webservices to achieve this as it is a much better user experience. The later will give you some great experience on building some nice applications.

Comment: I am new to asp.net, could you explain detaily